# Store JSON in multiple columns and concatenate them to query them

Tags: json, oracle, oracle18c

I have a table that currently has a extended column 32,768 bytes in size and so the database uses that space no matter if we put in 1 byte or all 32,768.

I store json in this column.

I am needing to reduce the size this column is taking.

Can I store the json in multiple columns and then concatenate the columns to work with the complete JSON?

For example

column has data:

```
    '{"REC_TYPE_IND":"1","ID":"999999","2nd ID":"1111","location":"0003","BEGIN_DT":"20000101","END_DT":"20991231"}'
```

I want to split it out like

column1:

```
   '{"REC_TYPE_IND":"1","ID":"999999","2nd '
```

column2:

```
   'ID":"1111","location":"0003","BEGIN_DT":"20000101","END_DT":"20991231"}'
```

The how to I use built in functions like json_value(column1 || column2,'location') to get a value?

The error I get when trying the above is:

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CHAR

Comment: Let's start with the statement you make in the very first paragraph of your question. Where did you get that information? It is 100% wrong. If you declare a column as `varchar2(32767)` and you store in it a string of length 100, that uses exactly 100 bytes of storage. Actually slightly more, because there is minimal overhead, and more, if you use multi-byte characters; but nothing to do with the max declared size of 32767 bytes. So - before even moving on from your first paragraph: WHAT GAVE YOU THAT IDEA?

Comment: I am guessing you do not have much experience working with extended columns in Oracle.  If you enable extended columns in 12c and up where it was introduced, behind the scenes it actually stores it as a CLOB  here is an example for your education   https://connor-mcdonald.com/2021/03/04/extended-varchar2-and-the-hidden-lob/

Comment: So that's what gave you this wacky idea? Do you understand how CLOBs themselves are stored in the database? The first 2000 bytes (which means the **entire** clob, if it's less than 2000 bytes) are stored inline, the same as a `varchar2`. The rest is stored elsewhere, and you have a LOB locator to tell you where. The locator takes 4 bytes on a 64-bit machine. It points to a location that is not used (when the string is short). Is that what you are concerned about - the overhead of the LOB locator?

Comment: the concern is merely the amount of space it is taking up.  I am converting the 32k+ column to 8x 4k columns and will combine.  Tested it out and it is work as intended.  Most data in the column is less than 4k but there are plenty that aren't.  This is reducing the disc space as I want.